# Git server and clone

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu-10.04, head, git-clone

I have create my git server with this link [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html) 
git clone working in server but when i clone my project on local machine 
i have a problem 
"warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout."
i used for clone "git clone http://domain.com/project.git"
i used virtual machine(domain.com =192.168.1.196) for git server and windows for local machine. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you access http://domain.com/project.git from your machine?

Comment: yes i can and all file for repo. enabled

Answer (score 1):

On the server run the following command in a new folder to initialize a new bare git repo...

```
git init --bare
```

On your local machine go to an existing folder of create a new one and run.

```
git init
```

Copy a file into this folder and execute.

```
git commit -am "New repository with a new file"
```

Then add your server as a remote.

```
git remote add myserver http://domain.com/project.git
```

Next step is to push to your server.

```
git push -u myserver master
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response. i used SCM Manager and it work perfectly